# set series driildown data with looping from array

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need a help about highchart

i want to set series drilldown data from array

this is the code if using manual

```
    series: [{
        name: 'Things',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [{
            name: 'Animals',
            y: 5,
            drilldown: 'animals'
        }, {
            name: 'Fruits',
            y: 2,
            drilldown: 'fruits'
        }, {
            name: 'Cars',
            y: 4
            drilldown: 'cars'
        }]
    }],
```

but i want to set the data for this series from array

this is my array:

```
var name = new Array('Animals', 'Fruits', 'Cars');
var y = new Array(5, 2, 4);
var drill = new Array('animals', 'fruits', 'cars');
```

this is the series using variable that set from array

```
    series: [{
        name: 'Things',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: data_drilldown //data_drilldown is a variable set from array
    }],
```

i have try many way to set value insert `data_drilldown` but have failed

can someone help me? how to set the value insert `data_drilldown` from array `name, y, and drill` with looping (for or any) so the output is same as manual one

thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple use `for`, that way:

```
var data_drilldown = [];
for(var i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
    data_drilldown.push({
        name: name[i],
        y: y[i], 
        drilldown: drill[i];
    });
}
```

Note: all arrays need to be the same length.